# Can you change the value in a column which has a foreign key constraint on it?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

If I have a table (`Table2`) which has a column which holds a foreign key reference to `Table1`, can I change the values in that column? (Provided the value it is being changed to is contained in Table1)

```
Table1

ID_Owner  |  Owner 
-----------------------
   1      |  Elizabeth 
   2      |  Bob 


Table2 

ID_Pet    |  Pet       |  ID_Owner 
-------------------------------------
   1      |  Fido      |  1 
   2      |  Rufus     |  2
```

(For example, if I wanted to change Fido's owner to Bob, could I change the `ID_Owner` from 1 to 2?)

Comment: What happened when you tried it (the answer is Yes, BTW)?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value in Table2, so long as the value you are changing it to is already contained in Table1.

If you want to change it to a value which is not already contained in Table1, you can add the value to Table1 first, and then change the value in Table2 to that value.

---

For example, if you wanted to change Fido's owner from Elizabeth to Bob, you can simply change Fido's `ID_Owner` from `1` to `2`. However, if you wanted to change Fido's owner from Elizabeth to Marie, you would have to add Marie to `Table1` first.

```
ID_Owner  |  Owner 
---------------------
   3      |  Marie
```

Now that the value exists in `Table1` (in the column which is being referenced), the value in `Table2` can be changed to `3`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, You can change the value of ID_Owner in Table 2 but the changed value must be a entry in Table 1.
Example

```js
UPDATE Table2
SET ID_Owner = @newID
```

Here, @newId is a parameter which contains the value to be updated
Note : The value of @newId can only be 1 or 2(based on values inside table1).
If you try to update with a value other than values which are in table1. It will throw you an error